# How to update a tkinter window

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I have a Main Windows and a AddItem Toplevel that I call by a menu. I want to update my Main window when a item is added by using the following codes but it fail:

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import ItemClass
def App():
    con = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/Stagiaire/Desktop/Ketrika/VCbase.db')
    mainWindow=Tk()
    menuBar=Menu(mainWindow)
    def addItem():
        ItemClass.AddItem()
        mainWindow.destroy()
        App()
    menuItem=Menu(menuBar,tearoff=0)
    menuItem.add_command(label="Add Item",command=addItem)

    menuBar.add_cascade(label="Item",menu=menuItem)

    cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(""" SELECT nomTraitement From traitement""")
    ItemRecord=cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    i=2

    
    variables=[]
    variablesP=[]

    for item in ItemRecord:
        itemLabel=Label(mainWindow,text=item,fg="white",bg="#202830")
        itemLabel.grid(row=i,column=0)
        Var=StringVar()
        VarP=StringVar()
        stock=Entry(mainWindow,textvariable=Var, font='Verndana 12',fg="#202830",bd=3)
        prediction=Entry(fenetre,textvariable=VarP, font='Verndana 12',fg="#202830",bd=3)
        prediction.grid(row=i,column=2)
        stock.grid(row=i,column=1)
        variables.append(Var)
        variablesP.append(VarP)
        i=i+1
```

Comment: What does It fails mean? You get an error, or it doesn't update? Also could you better describe the code so people have easier job on understanding it?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll improve the question and the code.Then,the failure is like this:   - it doesn't update , and when i close the application it returns :"_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed>"

Comment: All widgets have a `configure` method for changing them at runtime. Other widgets, such as listboxes, text widgets, and canvases, have other methods which let you modify their contents.